# Using multiple tailwind stylesheets

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss, monorepo, remix.run

I have three tailwind stylesheets that may be included on a single page. Due to the way they're included, it's not possible to set the import order to manage precedence.  Is it possible to tell tailwind or postcss to include another stylesheet, from another package, and produce just one "main" stylesheet?

My project is in a monorepo split into three different packages:

```
my-app
 ┕ tailwind.css
account-profile
 ┕ tailwind.css
ui
 ┕ tailwind.css
```

The `my-app` package is the main application, written in Remix, and it imports the others.  The `account-profile` package provides an interface inside the application to handle account management.  The `ui` package is a component library used by both `my-app` and `account-profile`.  When you navigate to the account profile in the application, it would load all three tailwind.css stylesheets.

Here's a gist to help explain why including multiple tailwind stylesheets causes problems: https://gist.github.com/WriteLock/10d2f632c9fa66e0d9dedfa291ed2f3a
The div with the `lg:block` class does not appear as it should because of the order that the stylesheets are imported.

The only solutions I've come up with either do not work or are not sustainable:

- @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss - Does not work across packages.
- Scoped CSS is experimental and tricky to use. Since the UI library will be used in various places, it wouldn't work for that case.
- Manually add any necessary tailwind classes to the `safelist` in the tailwind config in one of the packages, and skip importing the other two.
- Add the content paths for `account-profile` and `ui` packages to the tailwind config in `my-app`, i.e.:

```
content: [
  ...,
  "../account-profile/**/*.{ts,tsx}$",
  "../ui/**/*.{ts,tsx}$"
]
```

Comment: Is the whole project using only Tailwind, or do you have other css? If it is all Tailwind, it may help to use `@layer` directives which help control the declaration order. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer

Comment: There is at least one additional css file in the ui package.  We're trying to use as little css as possible but I expect the project will never be purely tailwind.

Comment: Also there is no problem with including custom css, the problem is that the built tailwind stylesheets will override each other in an order that we're unable to control.

Comment: I ask about other css, because I don't see you could be in a situation how tailwind css styles are competing. I would be interested to know. But if it is due to styles you have added in the main tailwind css file, then using `@layer` directives should resolve it.

Comment: A relatively simple case I experienced was with `.hidden` and `.lg:block`. The my-app stylesheet had both classes but the others only had the `.hidden` class. Since the my-app stylesheet was loaded first, and both selectors have the same specificity, an element with `class="hidden lg:block"` was always hidden. I had to add the lg:block class to the safelist as a quick fix, but need to find something more sustainable as this issue will grow as the application increases in scope.

Comment: Ok, I think that requires more knowledge about Remix than I have. I would have thought your third option to add all the content paths would make the most sense. Why isn't that working?

Comment: It probably would work but it tightly couples the packages with their specific paths, plus the goal is to have lots of packages imported similar to account-profile so it'd become troublesome to maintain this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245080/discussion-between-stickyuser-and-phunt).

Comment: I saw someone with a related problem and they used the `important` setting, not sure if that would help you, but might be worth a try. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important